# std: :array -- difference between size() and max_size()

Tags: c++, stl

What is the difference between size() and max_size() functions for std: :array in C++?

```
  array<int,5> arr{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
  cout << arr.size(); 
  /* Output : 5 */ 
  
 array<int, 5> arr{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
 cout << arr.max_size(); 
 /* Output : 5 */
```

Comment: `size` and `max_size` are part of "interface" of most containers. For fixed sized `std::array`, there are indeed the same; for `std::vector`, there would be different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is the difference between size() and max_size() functions for std: :array in C++?

The latter has prefix `max_`. There is no other practical difference between them for `std::array`.

The difference is conceptual. `size` is the current number of elements in the container, and `max_size` is a theoretical upper bound to how many elements the container could have. Since the number of elements in `std::array` is constant, the current number of elements is exactly the same as the number of elements there can ever be. For other containers, there is a practical difference.

Using the `max_size` member function of `std::array` is conceptually silly. It exists so that `std::array` conforms to the `Container` concept (e.g. named requirement), which allows it to be used uniformly with other containers, which is useful within templates.

Answer (score -2):

i think max_size() refers to the capacity of the array and not the actual size of the array.

Comment: while arrays are similar to other containers by having a `max_size` they don't have capacity.

Comment: Furthermore, in case of a container that does have a capacity such as `std::vector`, `std::vector::max_size` has no correllaction with `std::vector::capacity`.

Answer (score -2):

size () tell the number of elements in array and max_size() tell the capacity of array but as in array we have not ability to decide which data item is valid or which not .
as we write array<int,5>={1};
then array built is {1,0,0,0,0};
then it can not consider 0's as invalid items .
therefore size() and max_size() give same answere
as in
when we even make array without putting initializing it then also it have garbage value and it consider then as elements in array then give same output for size() and max_size() .
theoretically size() give number of elements and max_size() give capacity but array have element at all index from starting ether garbage value , 0 or putted by user therefore we get same output.